# What does gtag.js do that requires a regular function over an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, arrow-functions

I ran into this issue today where my gtag.js integration wasn't working when I was using an arrow function to update the datalayer, but did work when I used a regular function.

```js
// This updated the dataLayer, but did not post to Google
const gtag = (...args) => { window.dataLayer.push(args); };
gtag('config', 'xxx');
```

```js
// This updated the dataLayer, and triggered a post to Google
function gtag () { window.dataLayer.push(arguments); }
gtag('config', 'xxx');
```

**My question is, what exactly is gtag.js doing that means the regular function works here, but the arrow function doesn't?**

If I update both to also log `args`/`arguments` to console they have the same content being pushed to the datalayer, but somehow only the regular function then triggers the post.

Both these functions are being created and called from within an arrow function deep in my code, so I'm not directly providing the `gtag` method to gtag.js as far as I know?

Comment: It's all about `this`. Arrow functions don't provide their own `this` binding (they retain the `this` value of the enclosing lexical context) - from the bible https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this -- gtag, like jQuery utilize a block-scope `this`

Comment: Hm, so is gtag.js injecting some custom logic into `window.dataLayer.push` that requires the `this` context provided by the `gtag` function that I call?

Comment: I'm out of my depth here, but I suspect they're using `this` throughout their code and the meaning of that pointer is different when using the arrow func.